# How to draw a 3D curve in WPF?

Tags: wpf, 3d, draw

Is it possible to draw a 3D curve in WPF? i.e. Which classes do I need? Can you give me so code snippets.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To render a 3D scene in WPF, you have to use an element called `ViewPort3D`. This has a `Camera`, a collection of `Visual3D`. A concrete sub type of `Visual3D` is `ModelVisual3D`. This visual helps render the `Model3D`. All the 3D shapes are represented by a `GeometryModel3D` or the more complex `Model3DGroup` (all derive from `Model3D`). We just care about the property `GeometryModel3D.Geometry` (of type `Geometry3D`) here. Currently, WPF just supports ***only 1*** kind of `Geometry3D` called `MeshGeometry3D`. But this geometry consists of a large number of triangles. To define the triangles, it has a collection of `Point3D`s (`Positions`) representing the vertices of the triangles and a collection of `int` (`TriangleIndices`) used to indicate how to connect the vertices (saved in `Positions`) to make the actual triangles.

That means the curve you want to draw should have some shape, such as some kind of cylinder (like vermicelli) or just like a strip of cloth... Anyway it's not easy. The following demo code renders the curve as a thin strip (not round), however in fact we make it so thin that  you can just see it looks like a line (depending on how close we view the scene).

As I said above, what we need to build the curve is fill the info (`Positions` and `TriangleIndices`) for a `MeshGeometry3D`. We need some equation of the curve, make some loop to get a collection of Point3Ds (belong to the curve) and at the same time fill the `TriangleIndices` appropriately.

Here is the code detail:

**XAML**:

```
<Grid Name="grid">        
    <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="55,55,55" LookDirection="-1,-1,-1"
                               UpDirection="0,1,0" FieldOfView="20"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="1,0,-1"/>
                        <AmbientLight Color="Black"/>
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                   <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Red"/>
                                   <EmissiveMaterial Brush="#330000ff"/>
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                                <MaterialGroup>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Red"/>
                                    <EmissiveMaterial Brush="#330000ff"/>
                                </MaterialGroup>
                            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="geo"/>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                <RotateTransform3D>
                                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" 
                                                        Angle="0" x:Name="rot"/>
                                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                </RotateTransform3D>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        </GeometryModel3D>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
        <Viewport3D.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="rot">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" By="360"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="00:00:10"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Viewport3D.Triggers>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Note about the `Name` of the `MeshGeometry3D` in XAML code is `geo`, we need to refer to this to build the curve using code.

**Code behind**:

```
int k = 0;
for (float n = 0f; n < 1; n += 0.01f, k++) {
     //calculate the current Point3D based on the equations of the curve
     var x = -13 * Math.Pow(n, 3) - 12 * n * n;
     var y = 35 * Math.Pow(n, 5) - 13 * n * n + 3 * n + 1;
     var z = -30 * Math.Pow(n, 3) + 20 * n * n - n - 1;
     //the current Point3D
     var p = new Point3D(x, y, z);
     //here is where we make it thin, 
     //you can replace .1 with such as 10 to enlarge the strip
     var u = new Point3D(x, y - .1, z);
     geo.Positions.Add(p);
     geo.Positions.Add(u);                                              
     if (k > 0) {
          geo.TriangleIndices.Add(k);
          geo.TriangleIndices.Add(k - 1);
          geo.TriangleIndices.Add(k + 1);                    
          geo.TriangleIndices.Add(k);                    
     }
     geo.TriangleIndices.Add(k);
     geo.TriangleIndices.Add(k + 1);
     k++;
 }
```

**NOTE**: I highly recommend you to read about basic 3D concepts in WPF first, at least you should understand how to connect the points (in `Positions`) to indicate the triangle surfaces as what you want. Once understand that, you can understand the code above.